# Is the result of Matrix-vector multiplication a matrix or a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Take $A\vec{x}$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 & -5 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$.
Then if $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $A\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Now my question is, is $A\vec{x}$ a matrix or a vector? Because at sight, it just looks like a simple 2x1 vector with the $x$ value being $3$ and the $y$ value being $1$.

But thinking about it, technically $A$ was a system of equations (matrix) to start with, which means that every value inside it that was multiplied by $\vec{x}$ were just coefficients to another unknown set of variables. The long version of the matrix would be $A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 y_1 & 4y_2 & -5y_3 \\ 
1 y_1 & 0y_2 & 2y_3
\end{bmatrix}$ would it not?

So then in the end, would the final answer of $A\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$ really mean something else? Another system of equations with just 1 unknown and 2 rows??

Comment: Why do these need to be mutually exclusive objects?  Something can be both a matrix and a vector simultaneously.

Comment: Well isn't a matrix a system or equations and a vector.. just kind of like a point with a line drawn from it from the origin???
Like, there's a difference between just straight up $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and having $b_1$ = $3x_1$ and $b_2$ = $x_2$ so that $A = \vec{b}$

Comment: How about this then... if I talk about the result of simplifying $1+1$ and get $2$., what is $2$?  Is it a natural number?  An integer?  A rational number?  A real number?  A complex number?  etc...  Each of these objects are defined very differently.  The point is that we can and do many times switch between interpretations and definitions of what an object currently is out of convenience to suit our needs at the time.  The same can be said to be true here with your matrices.

Comment: A matrix is a two-dimensional array, usually of numbers. It might represent a system of linear equations, a linear transformation, or even simply be a table of values. In that context, a “vector” is just a matrix that happens to have only one row or column. The latter can also be an element of a vector space, however. For that matter, there are vectors spaces whose elements are matrices with more than one row or column. Now, you can certainly assign a geometrical meaning to one of these “vectors,” which is what you’re doing when you think of it as representing a directed line segment.

Answer (score 2):

A vector may be considered as a matrix with either one row or one column.

Thus the product above is both a matrix and a vector.